# iPhone doubles screenshots

Tags: iphone, photos.app

Whenever I take screenshots everything seems fine, but then when I wake up, in photos all my screenshots are doubled. Mixed in with each other randomly there are two copies of each screenshot. This always happens overnight some time, since I never see it happen. Anyone else have this happen?

Comment: Do you have any Siri shortcuts or other automation helping with any tasks?  While it wasn’t the exact same issue that you’re experiencing I once created an IFTTT recipe for iCloud photos, then had a few days pass where it wasn’t fresh in mind, then I couldn’t figure out what was happening until I suddenly realized full photos were not arriving to iCloud until overnight, once they arrived the IFTTT triggered.

Comment: Ok I’ll see if it’s an IFTTT trigger, I do use IFTTT. Ty.

Comment: That’s what it was, thank you! If you post as an answer I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check any automation triggers you may have such as IFTTT.

Specifically it seems that iCloud photos may wait until overnight to sync, thus causing the IFTTT to not trigger until overnight.